# Split multiple conjuncts in the goal

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Is there a tactic to split multiple conjuncts in a goal into subgoals?
If I have the goal P /\ Q /\ R, I want to split it to produce three subgoals at once:
P, Q, and R
I can't seem to find any info on this.

Comment: It's just `split.`

Comment: @djao split only splits it into two subgoals for me. So P /\ Q /\ R turns into P and Q /\ R

Comment: [stdpp](https://plv.mpi-sws.org/coqdoc/stdpp/stdpp.tactics.html) provides a `split_and!` tactic which seems to be precisely what you want

Comment: `repeat split.` does it.

Comment: You can write you own splitting tactic ([example here](https://github.com/Matafou/LibHyps/blob/master/LibHyps/LibDecomp.v)). That said if you really end up doing this very often, it may mean that you should start using records instead of chained `/\\`. 2 advantages: destruct takes one split, and adding an field to the record is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain tactics. Split twice to split into 3.

```
(* Goal P /\ Q /\ R *)

split; [|split].

(* 3 subgoals:
   - P
   - Q
   - R
*)
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, either

```
repeat split
```

Or

```
split; [|split; [|split]].
```

does it.